# Using Websocket with Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, passport.js

How do I access the passport login for the current session when someone opens a WebSocket connection?

I've found a nice project [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) which seems to work beautifully

```
app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('express-ws --- ', msg);
    });
    console.log('socket', req.user); //current user == req.user
});
```

But how would I go about getting this same information with a plain Websocket connection?

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3001 });

wss.on('connection', function(socket){
    //Where is the current user????
    console.log('connection');

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        console.log('message received', message);
    });
});
```

(this second connection does work just fine - but I can't for the life of me find any way to get the logged in info from Passport)

Comment: Currently I want to realize passport-wise authentication with `express-ws`. How did you implement the authentication middleware and what do your websocket connection requests look like?

Answer (score 21):

When you're creating your WS server, add a "verifyClient" parameter as follows to grab the session information:

```
  const wss = new (require('ws').Server)({
    server,
    verifyClient: (info, done) => {
      sessionParser(info.req, {}, () => {
        done(info.req.session)
      })
    }
  })
```

Where `sessionParser` is your `express-session` configured object.  This then allows you to access it within the websocket via `req.session`.  If you're using passport, you might want `req.session.passport.user`..

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the real answer

Comment: `ws` package, which `express-ws` uses, discourages use of `verifyClient` as described [in docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback) and with workaround in [this issue](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/377#issuecomment-462152231)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `req.session.passport.user` to access authenticated user id, one can use `ws.upgradeReq.session.passport.user`.

```
app.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('express-ws --- ', msg);
    });
    console.log(ws.upgradeReq.session.passport.user);
    /* keys can be found like
    for(var key in ws.upgradeReq.session.passport){
        console.log(key);
    }
    */
});
```

Comment: Please explain what's going on in your code. Just posting a code sample will not explain to the OP or future readers what went wrong with the original problem, or why your solution works.

Comment: @BHustus is it fine now?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the best solution, but we can drop the WS connection with the following code:

```
const wss = new webSocket.Server({ server, port: 9999})

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {

  // get token from url:  ..url..?token=your_JWT_TOKEN
  const params = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query
  const { token } = params

  // add token to headers (could be done on frontend)
  req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`

  // look for the user with token
  passport.authenticate(
    'jwt',
    {
      session: false
    },
    (err, user, info) => {
      // If no user close websocket
      if (!user) {
        console.log('Websocket disconnected due to invalid token')
        ws.close()
      }
    }
  )(req)
```

Comment: This does not work. Passport attempts to set headers and response codes on a response object that does not exist.